# How to add available when customer add to cart more available qty

Tags: magento2, product, addtocart, quantity, qty

How can I add the quantity not available error message to the quantity that can be added to the cart instead?

[image]

Result I expect

"The requested qty is non available, there are XXX qty available"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override this class: `vendor/magento/module-inventory-sales/Model/IsProductSalableForRequestedQtyCondition/IsSalableWithReservationsCondition.php:95`

'message' => __('The requested qty is not available'.$qtyLeftInStock)
and add this with message like above qtyLeftInStock

Result:
[image]